# How to add same tooltip for multiple text box using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net

I want to set same  title or tooltip for multiple textbox in the table. How to set the same title or tooltip for multiple textbox.I want to set this on document.ready function

Code

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="tblPercent" style="text-align:center">
                                            <thead>
                                            <tr style="font-weight:bold; text-align:center">
                                                <td style="width: 5%;" data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></td>
                                                <td>  </td>
                                                <td>IN Tier 1</td>
                                                <td >IN Tier 2</td>
                                                <td>OON</td>
                                                <td style="width: 8%">Not Covered</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                                 
                                            <tr class="hidden toggle advanced"">
                                                <td>
                                                    <span class="chkBoxcls">
                                                        <input id="chkboxIpMedical" class="chkBoxPer chkInP" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBox1" value="A1">
                                                    </span>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="text-align:left"><span id="lblA1" style="padding-left: 3%">IP Medical</span></td>
                                                <td><asp:TextBox id="IINTier1IpMedical" CssClass="TxtBox12 txt1A1 txtIPTier1 txtDataPopTier1 clearValueIpMed clearValueIp" title="InP21" onInput="computeValue('#IINTier1IpMedical','#IINTier2IpMedical','#OONIpMedical')"   runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span18" runat="server" class="pers">%</span></td>
                                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="IINTier2IpMedical" CssClass="TxtBox12 txt2A1 txtIPTier2 txtDataPopTier2 clearValueIpMed clearValueIp" title="InP22" onInput="computeValue('#IINTier1IpMedical','#IINTier2IpMedical','#OONIpMedical')" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span19" runat="server" class="pers">%</span></td>
                                           
                                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="OONIpMedical" CssClass="TxtBox12 txt3A1 txtDataPopOON clearValueIpMed txtIpOon clearValueIp" title="InP23" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span20" runat="server" class="pers">%</span></td>
                                           
                                                <td>
                                                    <span class="chkBoxcls">
                                                        <input id="chkNotCoveredIpMedical" type="checkbox"  title="InP2" class="chkNotCovIp"  runat="server">
                                                    </span>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                                
</table>
```

Comment: Your description would imply: `$("#tblPercent input").attr("title", "enter value here");` but I suspect there's more to it given that you have inputs in the `thead` and no `tbody` - so are they filters?  What's `InP11`?  Where are you getting the "new" tooltips from?

Comment: it seems the for all the textbox inside the table. what about each colum will have the different value. For an example i want 'IN Tier 1'='95' for  and IN Tier 2 ='0' and OON='5' . i have total more than 40 tr inside the table.